# Multiple User Story View in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter [story view](https://pub.dev/packages/story_view) for showing stories in our app. The story view runs perfectly but for any single story on tap, if story is complete it will pop on complete function. Now I want to run multiple user stories like WhatsApp, Instagram one-by-one if running story duration is complete show next user story automatically. I can'nt understand how to run next user story automatically. I am new on Flutter.

```
List<StoryItem> storylist = [];
onTap: () {
                  
                      storylist.add(StoryItem.pageVideo(
                        item['video'],
                        controller: controller,
                      ));

                      setState(() {});

                      showDialog(
                        barrierDismissible: true,
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          //     storylist = storylist.toSet().toList();

                          return StoryView(
                            storyItems: storylist,
                            onComplete: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                              setState(() {});
                             
                            },
                            repeat: false,
                            onVerticalSwipeComplete: (direction) {
                              if (direction == Direction.down) {
                                setState(() {});
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                setState(() {});
                              }
                            },
                            controller: controller,
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [AdvStory](https://pub.dev/packages/advstory), this package fits your use case.

```dart
AdvStory(
  storyCount: 5,
  storyBuilder: (index) {
   return Story(
      // Story media count
      contentCount: 5,
      contentBuilder: (contentIndex) {
        // You can return ImageContent, VideoContent, SimpleCustomContent
        // or you can create your own contents, see docs.
        return ImageContent(url: '');
      },
    );
  },
  trayBuilder: (index) => AdvStoryTray(url: ''),
)
```